# Error appears before submit in php form

Tags: php, forms

I have the following code but unfortunately $error appears as soon as the page loads, before clicking on submit. What am I doing wrong?

(filename= form.php)

```
<?php
$error="";
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Submit") {  

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if($name=="" || $email==""){
$error .= "Error: all fields are required";
}
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email)) {
$error .= "<br/> Error: Invalid email address";
}

if (isset($error) && ($error!=="")) {
    echo $error;
}
elseif (empty($error)){
    // this works no need to write here... send form.
    }
    }

echo<<<_END
<html><head><body>
<form method='post' action='form.php'>
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name" value='$name'>
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email" value='$email'>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</body>
</html>
_END;
?>
```

Comment: you better rewrite your code, it's a mess

Comment: I updated the code. I am new with php, can you point out why it is a mess please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($error) && (!$error=="")) {
echo $error;
```

}

if $error is set and $error equals nothing echo $error? 
$error is being set when you intialize it to "" in the first line and it is equal to ""

Just noticed the ! in the second part of the if. Do what the person below me said.

Comment: ok thanks for this, I updated the code (see above) however this does not solve my problem:
When the page is reloaded, the errors still display. It remembers the values from the last 'submit' action.

Comment: By reloaded do you mean refreshing or actually going to the page from another link? Refreshing will resend the post data so that is normal behaviour. If it's doing it by going directly to the page I'm a little lost as to why to be honest. Btw you don't need that END heredoc stuff, just close the PHP before the HTML starts.

Comment: ok thanks Rick, I see what you mean.
I thought that refreshing the page would take into account the $error="" at the top of the code and empty the variable $error.
By the way, how do I reset this form? My reset button does not work.

Comment: Also if I just put plain html without the heredoc stuff, then the <input... value='$user'> in my form does not work, in other words the user input dissapears upon submit.Thanks, L.

Comment: Ahh right, I didn't notice those values, I personally throw things like that in as standalone php tags rather than the way you did it but either works. Resetting the form: Give the reset button a type of submit then you can add code for it with the same concept as your other code doing an isset and a == reset. Then you can just blank those fields and not fire the submit code for the form itself.

Comment: Thanks, you have been an enormous help!
Two last things though - if you have time:

a. <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">
if (isset($_POST['reset']) && $_POST['reset'] == 'Reset') {
 echo $name;
}
How come this clears the values out since its not of type=reset? 
echo $name does not return anything back...

b. How exactly do you throw standalone php tags?
I tried <input type='text' name='name' value=<? $name?> /> and also

<input type='text' name='name'> <? $name ?> </input> and also

<input type='text' name='name'> <? global $name ?> </input>
but it doesnt work still...

Comment: the inline php aren't working for sure because your syntax is wrong and possibly because your copy of PHP might not have shortcodes enabled. To be safe write them like this <?php echo $name; ?> but even if you do have short codes enabled it would still be wrong, it should be <?=$name; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(!$error==""))` with `($error!==""))`.